# to get cdma dbm on android device

Tags: android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

I had tried this one to show my evdo dbm. 
   it could run on my emulator but couldnt on my real device, why? 
   is there somethinh wrong ?
   this my source code :

```
package com.cdbmsof2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CdBmSOF2MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView dateAndTimeLabel;
private Button closeButton; 
private int signalDBM = 0;

public class GetParams extends PhoneStateListener 
{

    @Override  
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
    {
         super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
         signalDBM = signalStrength.getEvdoDbm();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cd_bm_sof2_main);


    GetParams listener = new GetParams();
    TelephonyManager TelManager = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    TelManager.listen(listener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);             
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.start:
                Toast.makeText(this, "CDMA signal strength is " + this.signalDBM , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;                    
   }
}    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_cd_bm_sof2_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

this my manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cdbmsof2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CdBmSOF2MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cd_bm_sof2_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

any one would help me please? best regards.

Comment: Will you also calculate a % out of the dBm? Any idea on the dBm range or how to transform it into %?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the MODIFY permission into a READ permission as you're not modifying phone state, but trying to read it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code but the value of the `signalDBM` will not change. It will stay the same even if there is no internet connection at all. I am trying to do something similar and your code was of good help for me but now I face that problem. Does that program changes the values for you? Please let me know..